# Event listener to wait for all XMLHttpRequest inside iframe

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, iframe

I've a simple html page with an iframe

```
<html>
<head>
$('#page-wrapper').ajaxStop(function() {
  console.log("Page Loaded Completely." );
});
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Demo page<h3>
    <iframe id="page-wrapper" src="#company/profile"></iframe>
</body>
```

I want to execute a piece of java script after every XMLHttpRequest is complete for the page inside iframe. I've found a way to wait for all ajax requests using [ajaxStop](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) but the console message gets printed very early and it doesn't wait for even a single ajax request to finish.

document ready or load also doesn't work here as the page is not responded with a single html file, it is more like a single page application where the dom is available very early followed by request for lot of resource files and some 40-50 number of ajax requests before the page is finally finished.

I am looking for something like Chrome Dev Tools -> Network Tab and type "is:running" in the filters and you will only get the pending requests. Something that can give me the count for the number of active requests.

[image: Chrome Dev tool]

Answer (score 2):

In case an update as of year 2020, still have problems with **ajaxStop()** inside **iframe**, this method finally did the trick:

```
$('#my-iframe-id').load(function(){

    var instance = this.contentWindow.jQuery,
    doc = this.contentWindow.document;

    instance(doc).ajaxStart(function(){
        console.log('ajaxStart');
    });
    instance(doc).ajaxStop(function(){
        console.log('ajaxStop');
    });
    instance(doc).ajaxComplete(function(){
        console.log('ajaxComplete');
    });

});
```

In this thread use `#page-wrapper` as iframe id

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `ajaxStop` is a global event handler, and should be attached to the `document` level.

jQuery's `$.ajax` triggers these events internally whenever `$.ajax` is used to do an XMLHttpRequest, and the events are bound with `on()` so they should bubble, but likely only up to the closest document/window level, which would be the contentWindow of the iframe.

What you need to do is probably something like

```
$(function() {
    $('#page-wrapper').on('load', function() {
        var win = iframe.contentWindow || iframe;
        var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

        $(doc).ajaxStop(function() {
             // catch ajax in iframe
        });
    });
});
```

This does of course require that the iframe is from the same origin, and is not blocked by the same-origin policy.

Comment: Thanks adeneo, ajaxStop was still getting called at the very start.
When I put a breakpoint inside the `ajaxStop` `$.active` was zero but when I put a breakpoint in a random javascript function inside the 'company/profile' page, `$.active` had a non-zero value. So there were two instances of jQuery running, first one on the page and second inside iframe and I need to add the ajaxStop inside the iframe page and once that is called I need to raise an event which the parent page is litening to and did the post stuff.